# Why there is concept of undirected graph if we can make bidirectional directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Why we are classfying undirected graph if we can use directed graph having bidirectional edges?
What's the major benefit of using undirected graph over directed graph?
[Directed graph with bidirectional edges also looks like undirected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdVaE.jpg)

Comment: do not you think it is out of the syllabus on this page? visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what kinds of topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Having one undirected link, instead of two directed links going in opposite directions, halves the memory required to store an undirected graph.